# Selective Execution of Jupyter Notebook Cells

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I utilize Jupyter Notebook for my machine learning projects, appreciating its capacity to integrate code and documentation. However, I've encountered a challenge and have tried to identify potential solutions.

My Jupyter Notebook Project encompasses the subsequent tasks:

1. Pre-training a neural network
2. Finetuning the neural network

[image: Jupyter Notebook Example]

My objective is to enable the execution of either of the following:

1. Solely pre-training the network
2. Pre-training the network followed by finetuning

I've discovered that Jupyter Notebook offers the option to apply tags, and it seems prudent to implement a mechanism where I can designate two parameters: pretraining and finetuning, as demonstrated below:

- If **pretraining** is set to True, activate the "pretraining" tag.
- If **finetuning** is set to True, activate the "finetuning" tag.

Is there a feasible approach to achieve this functionality?

[image]